# Histogram in SQL without skipping values

Tags: sql

## Code I have

```
select 
    floor(value / 5) * 5 as binned_value,
    count(*) as qty
from 
    myTable
group by
    binned_value;
```

## Example

### Input

```
| id | value| 
|----|------|
| 1  | 0    |
| 2  | 4    |
| 3  | 3    |
| 4  | 12   |
```

### Output

```
| binned_value | qty |
|--------------|-----|
| 0            | 3   |
| 10           | 1   |
```

Which means there are 3 value between 0..5 and 1 value between 10..15.

## Problem

I want the output to be this:

```
| binned_value | qty |
|--------------|-----|
| 0            | 3   |
| 5            | 0   |
| 10           | 1   |
```

That is, I want any bin that has 0 qty to also be shown.

I know I can do this with a bunch of joins and unions, but `5`, the bin size, is a parameter.

It is possible to know beforehand the highest possible value.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik Just assume a generic SQL system with no proprietary functions.

Comment: ANSI SQL doesn't have a sensible way to generate a series to join with, that's why I was asking about the specifics

Comment: You're trying to "make" data where data doesn't exist. You'd have to use recursion or some sort of procedure to loop though and generate the possible values and then LEFT join to  your "mytable".  Both of those methods are very much RDBMS specific.  I know of no generic ANSI sql which could accomplish this independent of RDBMS.  Now if you have a numbers table which contained the top most range and all intervals between... it could be done.

Comment: First you need build the binned_value column. To do that you need calculate the max value for `floor(value / bin size)` and then build the column. from 0 .. step(bin size) .. max value. Last you will do the left join. So at least you will write a storeproc or a cte. We need RDBMS to write that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursive CTE to get multiples of 5 (in the example below II got 15, but you could increase it to whatever).  Then make your query a subquery and join to it.

```
WITH NumbersByFive AS
(
    SELECT n = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 5 FROM NumbersByFive WHERE n <= 15 

)
SELECT nbf.n AS binned_value,
       ISNULL(qty,0) AS qty
FROM
NumbersByFive nbf
LEFT JOIN
(
    select 
        floor(value / 5) * 5 as binned_value
        ,count(*) as qty
    from myTable b
    group by floor(value / 5) * 5
) Subqry
ON nbf.n = Subqry.binned_Value
```

Comment: You should calculate the value 15 from `myTable` instead of hard code.

Comment: I agree.  I was just throwing it together as an example.  Good point, though!

Answer (score 1):

Here I check what is the max value in myTable to create the bin list first

Here is the sqlFiddle [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e70f/25)

```
;WITH n(n) AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 5 
    FROM n 
    WHERE n + 5 < ( select m.Value 
                    from 
                    myTable m
                    where not exists (select Value 
                                      from mytable t 
                                      where m.Value < t.Value
                                     )
                  )
), 
CTE as 
(
  select 
      floor(value / 5) * 5 as binned_value,
      count(*) as qty
  from 
      myTable
  group by
      floor(value / 5) * 5
)
SELECT n AS binned_value,
       ISNULL(qty,0) AS qty
FROM 
    n  LEFT JOIN
    CTE on n.n = CTE.binned_value
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```